# What should I do after a ClamAV Scan found 2 virus-infected files on my computer?

Tags: security, malware, clamav, clamtk

I ran a virus scan on my computer using ClamAV.
ClamAV has found two virus-infected files.

Should I use the Quarantine Option on ClamTK?
What should I do in order to remove the viruses? 
5 or so viruses have been found on these 2 infected files.

The first file: "mixing console 101 setup.exe".
The second file: "avgas-setup-7.5.0.50.exe".

Help much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Depends on what files. I'd like to see the exact message from ClamAV, copy/paste or screenshot.

Comment: For some reason, the names of the files were gone from the Terminal output...

Comment: Calm down! This and your other question about a the doc with macros suggest you're stressing too much for nothing. ClamAV gives a lot of false positives with the PUA detection enabled (default setting). I suggest you install and use the GUI frontend, disable PUA detection and check that doc file with macros before anything else. Then, just to be safe check anything else you want. If any warnings please edit your question and post the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Stay calm
2. Delete the files if you can
3. Put the files in quarantine if you cannot delete them

Once they are in quarantine, they cannot "break out" especially if they're Windows executables that cannot infect your Ubuntu installation (provided you don't have wine installed)

That's it!  Well done! **:-)**